# Can I use same Alias and keystore file for different application for playstore upload

Tags: android, android-keystore

I need to upload my own new second Android application in playstore. I know it is possible to use same keystore file. But I don't have idea to use **same alias or different alias** need to generate for second application for playstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keystore is just **container** holding your keys (like jar for cookies), so from technical point of view is completely irrelevant if you keep all your keys in single keystore or you have them splited among many (you can even have separated keystore file for each key - nothing prevents that).

Alias is also irrelevant - it's just "human friendly name" for your key, just for your convenience. It also makes no difference technically, however you cannot have more than one keys using the same alias **in given keystore**:

> **KeyStore Aliases**
>
> All keystore entries (key and trusted certificate
>   entries) are accessed via **unique** aliases.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

However you can use the same alias in different keystores w/o any problems.

NOTE: You can technically sign all your apps with the same key but this is strongly discouraged. You should create separate key for each released app - that will make your life much easier when i.e. you will decide to sell your project for instance.

Comment: As I researched each alias can have different SHA1 Key technically.

Example: SigningKey.Keystore has 2 Alias name Alias1 & Alias2.

Alias1 SHA1: OB:CE:8F:FC:87:DD:02:99:97:58:2C:D3:06:D8:38:0E:A8:78:DE:07

Alias 2 SHA1 fingerprint: A4:D8:CE:DA:53:5A:DD:DA:70:74:96:76:6A:EC:0C:72:17:38:52:9B

Is there any conflict can happen in Playstore,If I use same certificate(same Alias) for both the application.

Comment: That's pretty obvious. Alias is just the label, nothing more. And `Alias1` and `Alias2` are **two different** labels, so sure it **must** work - not sure what you're proving here :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use same keystore to upload different apps, if all the apps belongs to you or your firm.

Comment: Can you clear me.Shall I use same Alias or need to generate different Alias.